# order by charindex >0 and SQL concat

Tags: sql, sql-server, vbscript

I want to order Recordset by setting priority when ID is in an array:

This is the comma separated **myString** which holds a series of ID: `,1,2,4,6,8,12,34,`

I use concat to add comma before and after ID so I can compare it against the string:

```
sql="select * from customers order by case when charindex( concat(','," & id & ",',') , '" & myString & "' )>0 then 1 else 0 end desc"
```

I get **syntax error** message. I am not sure if there is error in SQL structure as I used `concat` in deep structure or there is error in using quote and double quote?

Comment: Have you debugged your code to see what the actual SQL being generated is? If so, it'd be useful to add it to the question.

Comment: Thank you @Diado . I found the problem by your suggestion. I will post it as answer.

Comment: `concat(','," & id & ")` only one comma is enough.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the problem when trying to answer @Diado Comment. The parameter ID should be used in SQL context not as a variable in VbScript context. So I have changed the query to this and it works:

```
sql="select * from customers order by case when charindex( concat(',',id,',') , '" & myString & "' )>0 then 1 else 0 end desc"
```